# Kotlin: modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'initializer'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, migration

I'm working in a Java project and I'm in charge of migrating some classes to Kotlin. There's a Java abstract class which has the next method:

```
protected abstract boolean init(params) {
    ...
}
```

And this class is being extended in a public class, so I override the method like this:

```
@Override
protected boolean init(params) {
    ...
}
```

So, when trying to migrate this public class to Kotlin,

```
override protected fun init(params): Boolean{}
```

I get the error *Kotlin: modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'initializer'*, because the method's name *init* is a keyword in Kotlin. I know one way of solving this is changing the name of the method in the abstract class (eg. from init to initialize), but it has tons of usages in the project so I would like to know if there's a better way of solving this before spending time refactoring the whole project.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code seems to be syntactically incorrect in some other way. In Kotlin, `init` is a soft keyword which, in particular, is allowed as a function name. Please post a full code sample ([MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that reproduces the error.

Comment: Besides, you should use the `Boolean` type in Kotlin rather than `boolean`.

Comment: In Java, if the method you are overriding is public, the override must be public too.

Comment: What is this `params`? Can you post full method signatures? I tried to write this but it compiles fine for me.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Do not use protected keyword. You can use your method like this in public class.

```
override fun init(): Boolean {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. Why should we not use protected? Can you please 'edit' this answer with an explanation. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.